# Pandas "replace" with dict input returns different results depending on dict order (where dict has no order)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a `pandas` `Series` with values of `True`, `False` or `None`.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([True, True, False, False, None, None])
```

I want to replace it into 1, -1 or 0 respectively. 
But when I run the `.replace` command, I see that the results depend on the way I define the dictionary. For example, if I define the two following dicts, with the same keys and values, they should behave the same:

```
dict_1 = {None: 0, False: -1, True: 1}
dict_2 = {False: -1, None: 0, True: 1}
```

However, they do not!

```
s.replace(dict_1)
```

outputs

```
0    1
1    1
2   -1
3   -1
4   -1
5   -1
```

and

```
s.replace(dict_2)
```

returns

```
0    1
1    1
2   -1
3   -1
4    0
5    0
```

What is the reason for this? And how can I make sure that I get the behaviour I want (the second case, like with `dict_2`)?

[EDITED: problem exists in python 3.6.1, pandas 0.21.1. According to – @Andrey Berenda, problem does not reproduce in python 3.7 and pandas 0.25]

Comment: which version do you use?
I tried s.replace({None: 0, False: -1, True: 1}) and s.replace({False: -1, None: 0, True: 1}). The result is the same.
python3.7.4
pandas0.25.3

Comment: python 3.6.1,  pandas 0.21.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
mapping = {None: 0, False: -1, True: 1}

s.map(mapping)

0    1
1    1
2   -1
3   -1
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Or using replace, would work as well:

```
s.replace({True: 1, False: -1, None: 0})

0    1
1    1
2   -1
3   -1
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: It worked, even with the "problematic" order of keys - thanks! Can you explain why would `.replace` and `.map` behave differently?

Comment: I accepted your edit request although it's not an improvement, a "problematic" order does not matter. It just maps the keys to the values. I also added a working example of `replace`

Comment: I know the order should not matter - that's the reason for the question in the first place.